# Convert Integer Into Number(p,s) During Insert

Tags: oracle, numbers, integer, type-conversion

I have a Table in Oracle like:

```
create table TEST (num number(7,2))
```

And i want to insert a integer into that table like that:

```
insert into TEST (num) values (5555522)
```

I'am searching for a way to convert the integer "5555522" automatically into the number(5,2) value so that the record contains 55555.22 instead of 55555. Is there some kind of function like "`setscale(5555522, 2)`" which just interprets the last 2 numbers as decimal place?

I already checked the `to_number()` Funktion in the Oracle docs. But it expects a proper formatted inputstring like to_number('55555.22', 99999D99) which is not suitable in my case.

Comment: How about 555552 --> you want it as 55555.2 , if I guess right Or 5555.52 ? Only for these complications, there nothing built in to handle this.

Comment: Yes, if i use 555552 then it should be converted to 5555.52

Comment: If so dividing by 100 do the job cleanly as mentioned in an answer below. But please make sure, you append zeroes to the end, if numbers having less than 2 decimal places.

Comment: Before that make sure that you give enough space to store the number. In your example you took data type number(5,2) and want to insert 55555.22, oracle will not allow this. number(5,2) means total length is 5 including 2 precisions.

Comment: @some_coder The largest value you can fit in a `number(5,2)` column is `999.99`.

Comment: @san: thanks, my fault. i'll edit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle should do that implicitly for you, after you divided by 100 :

```
insert into TEST (num) values (5555522/100)
```

EDIT : Like you said, it wont fit, you would need to change your table in order to do it :

```
create table TEST (num number(7,2))
```

Comment: That still won't fit into a number(5,2) column.